# Flutter Container Dynamic Height

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app where I show my notes.
On the left, I show the colors selected by the user with a height of 200 depending on the text size. How can I adjust the height of the color line depending on the text size?

[image]

```
return Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(),
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      onLongPress: () {},
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 8.0,
            height: 200.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color((int.parse('0x${list[idx].color}'))),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0))),
          ),
           Flexible(
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Title',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 6.0),
                  Text(
                    'No, you misunderstood. The maximum number of characters is 150. Container height changes according to variable text size. That's fine here. What doesn't change with different text size is the line length on the left side.

  '
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: how you are using this `Container`

Comment: I show a maximum of 300 characters in the container. Therefore, their heights can be different.

Comment: Actually it will be flexible height by default, can you simplify the snippet &  include sample data on the widget.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? containers still 200 px, but the color line same height as text, possibly smaller then container? or containers height depending on text size?

Comment: When I don't type 200px it doesn't show the color space on the right. I want the line length to change dynamically.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh does not appear by default.

Comment: Can you update with sample data, I like to give a try

Comment: So, you want container to be of fixed size and the size of the line to change dynamically according to the text.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. The maximum number of characters is 150. The height of the container changes according to the variable text size. There is no problem here. What doesn't change with different text size is the line length on the left

Comment: You can use this text, which is 200 characters. I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need actually:

[`IntrinsicHeight`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html)

```
    SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: IntrinsicHeight(
                      child: Card(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
                                            topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0))),
                                    width: 10,
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 10,
                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    children: const [
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                          child: Text(
                                              '****** Long data\n\n\n very very long and lot more \nand \nmore'),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]